# how to downgrade JAVA

Tags: command-line, software-installation, java, downgrade

I'm new to linux and I want to install some software. When I downloaded it and launched it with the sh command (I just followed instructions, so I'm not sure what that command is for) the terminal displayed this:

> No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
>   The version of the JVM must be at least 1.6 and at most 1.6.
>   Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.
>   You can also try to delete the JVM cache file

Can someone help me to install this? If so please be specific with everything since this is my first time using Linux.

This is what I'm trying to install:

https://familysearch.org/indexing/get-started-indexer

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no need to "downgrade"; multiple *simultaneous* versions are supported. You can install Java 6, something like

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Then you can do something like (depending on platform)

```
export INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you find what command you used, you might be able to get other help, like if the command was broken, or may need other packages.

You probably just need to install openjdk-6-jre like Elliot said, but just in case, you might as well.